# How do I find out who was last to modify file in accurev (command line)?

Tags: accurev, blame

I am writing command line tool which builds content of the stream in accurev and then notifies users that broke the build.
I can get the list of files promoted to the stream with command:

```
    accurev.exe stat -fex -d -s <Sentry_stream> -R .\
```

It outputs modified file:

```
    <AcResponse
        Command="stat"
        Directory="C:/Users/user"
        TaskId="12345">
      <element
          location="\.\file1.txt"
          dir="no"
          executable="yes"
          id="4867375"
          elemType="text"
          size="4909"
          modTime="1406904529"
          hierType="parallel"
          Virtual="140429\1"
          namedVersion="Sentry_stream\1"
          Real="129377\2"
          status="(member)"/>
    </AcResponse>
```

How do I find out who was last to modify it?

**UPDATE:**
The right combination for my problem was this:

```
    accurev translist -fx -s <Sentry_stream>
```

which produces list of current transactions and which I parse get the range for this:

```
    accurev hist -t <range of transactions> -s <Sentry_stream>
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the hist command.

accurev hist -t now "filename"

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to check out the `annotate` command. In the graphical Accurev program, you can use a slider on the top to traverse the file's change history from one promotion to the other. At each selected promotion, the program will show the file as it was when it was checked in. Each line displayed in the file will be prefixed by information about the change, including the username, date, and transaction number.

The Accurev `annotate` command is equivalent to the `blame` command under Subversion (or `svn` as it is named on the command line).